# Date comparision

Tags: linq

In LINQ, I write a query for data, which is *between* two dates. In this case I am not getting data. When user enters same date as *from date* and *to date* the data is not displaying while there are data for that particular date.

This is my LINQ query.

```cs
var result =  from MaterialStatus in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_MatReq_NewItemReq_M
join CurrentStatus in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_StatusMaster_M 
    on MaterialStatus.ReqCurStatus equals CurrentStatus.StatusId
join Employee in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_Emp_Master_M
    on MaterialStatus.Indentor equals Employee.EmpId
where (MaterialStatus.CreatedOn >= dt.Date 
    && MaterialStatus.CreatedOn <= dt1.Date)
select *****************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
var upperDate = dt1.Date.AddDays(1);
...
where (MaterialStatus.CreatedOn >= dt.Date
    && MaterialStatus.CreatedOn < upperDate
```

This way the expression can be converted to a [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) SQL predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dt1` is in reality greater that `dt`, you could use

```
    var result =  from MaterialStatus in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_MatReq_NewItemReq_M
                             join CurrentStatus in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_StatusMaster_M on
                             MaterialStatus.ReqCurStatus equals CurrentStatus.StatusId
                             join Employee in materialRequistionEntities.Tbl_Emp_Master_M
                              on MaterialStatus.Indentor equals Employee.EmpId
                              where (MaterialStatus.CreatedOn.Date >= dt.Date && MaterialStatus.CreatedOn.Date <= dt1.Date)
                              select *****************
```

Notice `CreatedOn.Date` to deal with the hour/minute/seconds/milliseconds components

Comment: Mr.John Gathogo i am not getting Date at MaterialStatus.Createdon.

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Isn't CreatedOn a datetime field? If it is, you should be able to do `.Date`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be ok.

```
where (MaterialStatus.CreatedOn.Value.Date >= dt.Date && MaterialStatus.CreatedOn.Value.Date <= dt1.Date.AddDay(1))
```