# EntityFramework 6.1.3 and MySQL DbFunctions.TruncateTime does not exist?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Trying to get a count of things entered today using this query.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var unitsPassedToday = await this.db.Sessions
        .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FinishTime) == today)
        .CountAsync();
```

Getting the following exception:

```
FUNCTION db.TruncateTime does not exist
```

I swear I've used this function before. I do not have any references to System.Data.Entity, which is the only solution I've found using a Google search. Is this some kind of bug with the MySQL implementation of EntityFramework? Obviously I could just write a stored procedure that returns this information, but I kinda wanna know why this isn't working?

MySQL server is 5.5.23-enterprise.

Feeling kinda dumb right now, seems like this should be a simple problem and I'm just overlooking something simple...

Edit:

Here is the SQL Entity Framework generates...

```
SELECT
`GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `sessions` AS `Extent1`
WHERE (TruncateTime(`Extent1`.`finish_time`)) = @p__linq__0) AS `GroupBy1`
```

I'm pretty sure TruncateTime isn't a valid MySQL function, why would it be calling that? I guess I should also add I'm using EDMX diagrams and not code first. I have added the codeConfigurationType in my web.config to target MySQL though...

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

MySql.Data.Entity is version 6.9.6.0

Comment: You shouldn't truncate the date anyway, for performance reasons. Use a [date interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163835/861716).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem people using stored procedure.

```
Create FUNCTION TruncateTime(dateValue DateTime) RETURNS date return Date(dateValue);
```

So it's very, very messy. But except of using stored procedure I've used this variant.

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

var newCustomersCount = _context
  .Customers
  .Where(x => x.RegisterDate > yesterday)
  .ToList()
  .Where(x => x.RegisterDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
  .Count();
```

We do selection of all records that newer than yesterday. .ToList() executes a query and then we're filtering what we want. This method selects minimum of necessary records.

Comment: Seems hacky. From what I understand this is Oracles issue on not fully implementing the DbFunctions functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on codeproject.com

I have tested the solution, worked for me! hope it helps

```
var data1 = context.my_model.Where(x => x.region_name == "Hong Kong" 
                        && x.price_date.Value.Year == dt.Year
                        && x.price_date.Value.Month == dt.Month
                        && x.price_date.Value.Day == dt.Day).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime has no Value property... it has a Date property but EF can't translate that to MySQL ..

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs it...
In the Hamad's example He uses an nullable DateTime? so, it has the 'Value' property...
If you have a non nullable Datetime, the example it's ok like this:

```
var data1 = context.my_model.Where(x => x.region_name == "Hong Kong" 
                    && x.price_date.Year == dt.Year
                    && x.price_date.Month == dt.Month
                    && x.price_date.Day == dt.Day).ToList();
```