# Entity Framework 6 - DbFunctions.AddHours error

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a task to fetch a set of entities for a specific period of time.
I'm using code first approach and MySql server.

With the code

```
IQueryable<Entity> query = dbContext.Set<Entity>().AsNoTracking();

Entity[] entities = (from e in query
               let last = (from ee in query orderby ee.Id descending select ee).FirstOrDefault()
               where e.Timestamp >= DbFunctions.AddHours(last.Timestamp, -hours)
               select e).ToArray();
```

And the following SQL generated by EF 6.1.3

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Timestamp`
FROM `Entities` AS `Extent1` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
`Extent2`.`Id`, 
`Extent2`.`Timestamp`
FROM `Entities` AS `Extent2`
 ORDER BY 
`Extent2`.`Id` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `Limit1` ON 1 = 1
 WHERE `Extent1`.`Timestamp` >= (AddHours(`Limit1`.`Timestamp`, -(@p__linq__0)))
```

I face an error

```
Failed in 6 ms with error: FUNCTION mydb.AddHours does not exist
```

And indeed I haven't got that function at DB side.
Does anybody know how those `DbFunctions` work?

**UPD**

Similar questions

[EntityFramework 6.1.3 and MySQL DbFunctions.TruncateTime does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834517/entityframework-6-1-3-and-mysql-dbfunctions-truncatetime-does-not-exist)

[how to use canonical functions in Entity Framework and Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235304/how-to-use-canonical-functions-in-entity-framework-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for now - just added an implementation of the function in `DbInitializer`

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddHours(timeValue datetime, addValue int) RETURNS datetime
        RETURN DATE_ADD(timeValue, INTERVAL addValue HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a stored function of your database, but that does not exist. The solution is to properly create the `AddHours` db function. More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Comment: That is what I actually did, but why there's nothing said about I should have created the function manually before using it with DbFunctions? I assumed, it is being created on fly while EF generates an SQL query.

Comment: @JohnSmith it is not created by EF. That would involve the code figuring out what your intention is. In this moment this is not possible, hence your runtime exception. The EF loads the objects generated based on your existent entities and your query will not generate them.