# EF Core equivalent of the LINQ query

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a logic in c# where I should filter records based on the difference between two datetime columns

```
var users = repository.GetAll().Where
            (
                userType => userType.CreatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value.Subtract(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value).TotalHours > 6 &&
                userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value.Subtract(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value).TotalHours < 150
             );
```

Get All method from repository

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            var obj = dataContext.Model.GetEntityTypes();

            return dataContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

However, the query is not actually executing on the server based on what I see on mini-profiler

```
SELECT "userType".usertypeid, "userType".created_by, "userType".created_ts, "userType".isdelete, "userType".updated_by, "userType".updated_ts, "userType".usertypecode, "userType".usertypename
FROM usr.usertype AS "userType"
```

I tried this and it does not work either

```
var users = repository.GetAll().Where
            (
                userType => userType.CreatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                EF.Functions.DateDiffHour(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value, userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value) > 6
             );
```

EF Core version 2.2.4

ASP.NET Core 2.2

Just wanted to know how I can achieve this in EF-Core

Update 1:

If I am using normal filters its executing as expected just to put that aside

```
SELECT "userType".usertypeid, "userType".created_by, "userType".created_ts, "userType".isdelete, "userType".updated_by, "userType".updated_ts, "userType".usertypecode, "userType".usertypename
FROM usr.usertype AS "userType"
WHERE ("userType".created_ts IS NOT NULL AND "userType".updated_ts IS NOT NULL) AND ("userType".usertypecode = 'INT')
```

Update 2:

added code for repository get all method

Update 3: my back end is Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

update 4: Josh's answer didn't work either

```
var users = dataContext.UserTypes.Where
            (
                userType => userType.CreatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
                EF.Functions.DateDiffHour(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value, userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value) > 6 &&
                EF.Functions.DateDiffHour(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value, userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value) < 150
             );
            return Ok(users.ToList());
```

Comment: What type are you returning from your repository? IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Comment: repository.DBSetUsers.Where(....).GetAll(). Reverse the request.

Comment: I'd say don't use a repository model with EF Core.

Comment: We need to know what's inside `repository.GetAll` method. Can you post that as well please?

Comment: @Sourcerer It didn't work. I am using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL by the way if that changes ow db functions behave.

Comment: Did Josh's answer work?

Comment: You shouldn't do any processing on `CreatedTimeStamp`, it kills performance and it makes you dependent on supported features. Just check if it's between a range of two variables. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163835/861716).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the way you are doing it.

```
var users = repository.Where
        (
            userType => userType.CreatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
            userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.HasValue &&
            EF.Functions.DateDiffHour(userType.CreatedTimeStamp.Value, 
            userType.UpdatedTimeStamp.Value) > 6
         ).GetAll();
```

pseudo code

Comment: this is not a fully written out answer