# How can I remove the time part from a nullable datetime in where condition of Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I  have a trouble with my existing Linq statement to apply the nullable datetime model value in where condition . When I apply the datetime with shortdatestring(), the following error is shown:

> .Where(ti => ti.Outer.EmpCode == __empcode_0 && ti.Outer.ClockDateFormatted == __ToShortDateString_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Here  is the Code

Attendance model

```
public string Code { get; set; }
public DateTime? ClockedDate { get; set; }

public ICollection<Attendance> GetClockList(string code, DateTime datefrom)
{
    ICollection<Attendance> data = new List<Attendance>();
    data = (from log in ctx.Attendance
            join emp in ctx.Employee on log.EmpCode equals emp.EmployeeID.ToString()
            where log.EmpCode == empcode
            && log.ClockedDate.Value.ToShortDateString() == datefrom.ToShortDateString() // Here I have to give the ClockedDate without time 
            select new Attendance 
            {
              
                EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
                ClockedDate = log.ClockedDate,

            }
            ).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

But the error is showed while giving  the datetime  with `shortdateString()` in where condition

Comment: Have you tried using the [`DateTime.Date` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0)? For example: `log.ClockedDate.Value.Date == datefrom.Date`?

Comment: Don't transform database columns before comparing, it kills performance. [Use a date interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163835/861716).

Answer (score 3):

if you use ms sql you can try this

```
.....

  where log.EmpCode == empcode
         && EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(log.ClockedDate, datefrom)==0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 && log.ClockedDate?.Date == datefrom.Date
```

but if that doesn't work you will probably need [EF Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions).